# How to use File-Rename aka Perl's rename in Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

There's tons of `rename` examples out there, but most of the time, these are for Unix/Linux users. What about if I want to use it using [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, go to https://strawberryperl.com/, then install the appropriate build (64 or 32 bits).

Now you have Perl and some utilities, but not the `rename` command.

To install it, open a `cmd`.exe terminal, then

```bash
cpan File::Rename
```

Now, the command is accessible.

```
file-rename
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -0 ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -d ] [ -u [enc]]
    [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]
```

A guide with some examples of using this utility: [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895)

---

To use the quoting style of 'Linux' instead of "DOS", better use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to use the `rename` command line with 'single quotes'.

Comment: cpan's `-i` switch is implied if you don't have any other switches. You can just type `cpan File::Rename`.